# Count rows per set (group of values)

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I use PostgreSQL. Given sets of groups such as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (
   id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO t (id, value) VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'B'),
(2, 'B'),
(2, 'A'),
(3, 'A'),
(4, 'A'),
(4, 'B'),
(4, 'C');
```

I wish to count rows per set and achieve the following result:

```
{'A', 'B'}: 2
{'A'}: 1
{'A', 'B', 'C'}: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to aggregates strings. But your desired result shows *arrays*. Use the simpler [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) for that.

Either way, you need to aggregate twice for your desired result:

```
SELECT values, count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT id, array_agg(value ORDER BY value) AS values
   FROM   t
   GROUP  BY id
   ) sub
GROUP  BY values
ORDER  BY ct;
```

Typically, it's **faster** to use `ORDER BY` once in a subquery, instead of adding it to the aggregate function (which results in one sort per group):

```
SELECT values, count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT id, array_agg(value) AS values
   FROM  (SELECT id, value FROM t ORDER BY 1, 2) sub
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e8b0c354cc578d7a41bf16bcb826fc0d)*

See:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15850510/939860)

Answer (score 0):

I found the function `group_concat` for MySQL or `string_agg` for PostgreSQL:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f994/3